# What does Mage:: correspond to?

Tags: class, object

I just had one of those moments where I realized I don't understand something.  What does the Mage part in say `Mage::helper` or `Mage::log` represent?

There is no `class Mage{ .. }` in Magento.

Thanks for your understanding on what is probably an obvious answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Mage class** is present in

> {magento root}/app/Mage.php

you can get helper function and log function definition

Answer (score 6):

As Meenakshi mentioned, there is a class Mage.

`Mage::log()` and `Mage::getModel()` are [static functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Nowadays you should avoid static function at all costs. There are a few little exceptions. Just google for static bad and/or when to use static and you get lots of blog posts and stackoverflow answers :-)